# CakePHP on a Mac - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, cakephp, mamp

I have been creating a CakePHP application on my Linux computer and running it using Lampp. Everything has been going well.

I have passed the project to a designer to do some layout updates who is using a Mac and running Mamp.

When he try to run the project he is receiving the following error:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://localhost:8888/. It may be down for maintenance or configured
>   incorrectly. Here are some suggestions: Reload this webpage later.
>   HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Why would this error occur on his Mac but not my Linux?

**EDIT:**

The Server log is showing the following:

> [Sun Sep 04 20:07:50 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by
>   server configuration: /Users/Jamie/Sites/.DS_Store [Sun Sep 04
>   20:07:52 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server
>   configuration: /Users/Jamie/Sites/Glecto/.DS_Store, referer:
>   http://localhost:8888/ [Sun Sep 04 20:15:52 2011] [notice] caught
>   SIGTERM, shutting down [Sun Sep 04 20:15:55 2011] [notice] Digest:
>   generating secret for digest authentication ...

Comment: Check the server logs, they should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: how do I find the server logs (on a mac)?

Comment: If you're using the native Apache web server, logs are in /var/log/apache2. If it's installed via MacPorts or Homebrew, they'll be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem recently using MAMP. I copied a plain php site from online to local for testing and the site kept giving me that error when I browsed to it locally. It turned out to be the permissions on the files. I had to go through the files and folders and change the permissions. Hope this helps